# Mapbox : Bulk markers breaks down browser

Tags: mapbox

Could anyone please help me on this,

I am using map box to plot different markers around 10,000+ in a window using GeoJSON format. While loading so, the browser window will get stuck and the user is not able to perform any actions. Is there any other alternative way to get rid of this or optimizing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Mapbox-GL-JS](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js). The guys at mapbox have implemented [a smart strategy](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/introducing-geojson-vt/) to parse and visualize large GeoJSON files using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Additionally, MapboxGL uses WebGL to visualize the data, so it should perform better with large datasets.

Other options include using an Html5 Canvas to render the data. Here is an example with Leaflet and Canvas overlay: http://bl.ocks.org/sumbera/11114288

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out to optimize the loading & performance :
[Optimizing data in mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/help/data-optimize/)